Confirmation Modal in Infinite Loop on Browser Back Button
I'm trying to implement a confirmation modal that appears when the user tries to navigate away from a page with unsaved changes. The modal correctly appears when the browser's back button or a "previous" button on the page is clicked, but when I confirm the action, the modal enters an infinite loop, continuously opening again instead of navigating away. This issue only occurs with the back button or the "previous" button; when navigating via other links, everything works as expected.
The modal works fine when clicking on links or buttons that trigger navigation to a specific path (e.g., from a header link), but it enters an infinite loop when confirming navigation triggered by the browser's back button or the "Previous" button in the form.
Without window.history.pushState(null, '', location.pathname + location.search);, the modal doesn't appear at all on back navigation, but with it, the modal keeps reappearing in an infinite loop when trying to confirm back navigation.
How can I prevent the modal from entering an infinite loop and correctly navigate away when the user confirms the back navigation?
`const EstimateRequestPage = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);

  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const { isDirty, setIsDirty } = useIsDirty();

  const { handleNavigate, renderModal } = usePreventLeave(isDirty);

  return (
    <Container>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {/* Form fields... */}
        <ButtonGroup>
          <PreviousButton variant="outlined" onClick={() => handleNavigate(-1)}>
            Previous
          </PreviousButton>
          <RequestButton variant="contained" type="submit">
            Submit
          </RequestButton>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </form>
      {renderModal()}
    </Container>
  );
};`



`import { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import ConfirmationModal from '@/components/ui/modal/Modal';

export const usePreventLeave = (isDirty) => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [pendingPath, setPendingPath] = useState(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handlePopState = (event) => {
      if (isDirty) {
        window.history.pushState(null, '', location.pathname + location.search);
        setIsModalOpen(true);
      }
    };
    window.history.pushState(null, '', location.pathname + location.search);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);
    };
  }, [isDirty, location.pathname, location.search]);

  const handleNavigate = useCallback(
    (path) => {
      if (isDirty) {
        setPendingPath(path);
        setIsModalOpen(true); // Show modal
      } else {
        navigate(path); // Navigate if not dirty
      }
    },
    [isDirty, navigate]
  );

  const handleConfirm = useCallback(() => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
    if (pendingPath === null) {
      navigate(-1); // Back navigation
    } else if (pendingPath) {
      navigate(pendingPath); // Navigate to pending path
    }
    setPendingPath(null);
  }, [navigate, pendingPath]);

  const handleCancel = useCallback(() => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
    setPendingPath(null); // Reset state
  }, []);

  return {
    handleNavigate,
    renderModal: () => (
      <ConfirmationModal
        open={isModalOpen}
        handleClose={handleCancel}
        handleConfirm={handleConfirm}
        messageId1="Leave page?"
        messageId2="Unsaved changes will be lost."
        confirmButtonId="confirm_button"
      />
    ),
    setPendingPath,
  };
};
`


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The problem is when you confirm navigation, the handleNavigate function might trigger a state change that causes handlePopState to run again, leading to an infinite loop. Try the code below i have provided use event.preventDefault() in place of window.history.pushState() and also add event listener and remove event listener once component unmounts & also remove location.pathname and location.search from useeffect dependency array.


useEffect(() => {
    const handlePopState = (event) => {
      if (isDirty) {
        // Prevent the default behavior and show the modal
        event.preventDefault();
        setIsModalOpen(true);
      }
    };

    // Adding event listener for popstate
    window.addEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);

    // Clean up the event listener on component unmount
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);
    };
  }, [isDirty]);




What I’ve Tried:
I initially tried using event.preventDefault(); to detect back navigation and display a modal. However, I found that I cannot prevent the default popstate event in the browser, which makes this approach insufficient.

As a workaround, I tried the following method:
When the component mounts, I added a new history entry with window.history.pushState(null, '', location.pathname + location.search);.
When the back button is pressed, I added another history entry with the same method so that the history stack looks like this: A -> B -> B. This ensures that when the user tries to go back from B, they stay on B, and the modal appears.

The Problem:
The modal correctly appears when the user presses the back button, but when they confirm the action in the modal, I can’t navigate them back to the previous page (A). The browser remains on the current page (B) after the modal confirmation.
